# rest_framework custom order_by

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filters

let's see if I can ask the questions correctly?

**model.py**

```
class Point(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(
        "nome del sistema",
        max_length=128,
    )
    x = models.FloatField(
        "cordinata spaziale x",
    )
    y = models.FloatField(
        "cordinata spaziale y",
    )
    z = models.FloatField(
        "cordinata spaziale z",
    )
    distance = float(0)

    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.name}"

    @property
    def get_distance(self):
        return self.distance

    @get_distance.setter
    def get_distance(self, point):
        """
        ritorna la distanza che ce tra due sistemi
        """
        ad = float((point.x-self.x) if point.x > self.x else (self.x-point.x))
        bc = float((point.y-self.y) if  point.y > self.y else (self.y- point.y))
        af = float((point.z-self.z) if point.z > self.z else (self.z-point.z))
        return (pow(ad,2)+pow(bc,2)+pow(af,2))**(1/2)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "point"
        verbose_name_plural = "points"
```

in the particular model there are two defs which calculate, save and return the distance with respect to the point we pass them

**wenws.py**

```
class PointViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    modelo generico per un systema
    """
    queryset = Point.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PointSerializers
    filterset_class = PointFilter
```

in the wenws not that much particular to explain and base base the only thing we have to say and that as filters I use 'django_filters'

**filters.py**

```
import django_filters as filters
import Point

class CustomOrderFilter(filters.CharFilter):

    def filter(self, qs:QuerySet, value):
        if value in ([], (), {}, '', None):
            return qs
        try:
            base =  qs.get(name=value)
            for point in qs:
                point.get_distance = base
            qs = sorted(qs, key= lambda x: x.get_distance)  
        except Point.DoesNotExist:
            qs = qs.none()
        return qs


class PointFilter(filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):

    security = filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=security_choices
    point= CustomCharFilter(
        label = "point"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Point
        fields = {
            'name':['exact'],
        }
```

now the complicated thing with 'CustomCharFilter' I pass in the http request the name of the system which then returns to me in the filter as value after I check that it is not empty and I start with returning the point that I have passed with `base = qs.get ( name = value)`
to then calculate and save the distance for each point with `point.get_distance = base '' on the inside of the for, at the end I reorder the QuerySet with` qs = sorted (qs, key = lambda x: x.get_distance) '' the problem that both with this way and with another that I have tried the QuerySet it 'transforms' into a list and this does not suit me since I have to return a QuerySet in the order of here I want. I don't know how to do otherwise, since order_by I can't use it since the distance is not inside the database
can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is that you want to filter from a python function which cant be done in a query, as they only speak SQL.

The easy slow solution is to do the filtering in python, this might work if there are just a few Points.

```
points = list(Point.objects.all())
points.sort(cmp=comparison_function)
```

The actual real solution is to port that math to Djangos ORM and annotate your queryset with the distance to a given point, this is quite an advanced query, If you tell us your database server you use we can probably help you with that too.

ps. There is an `abs()` function in python to get absolute value instead of the if/else in `get_distance`

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, then if I turn it into a list later it returns me an error for the one who says he wants a QuerySet and not a list, and the database I use is MySQL

Comment: hi, look I have updated my progress that I have made today and I have tried to better explain my problem

Comment: I totally understand the problem, but you will either need to do it all in python, so after any querysets are evaluated, or within a queryset, but then you need to use the ORM for it and do the math in SQL.